# Subversion commit failed Merge of file: 200 OK post-commit hook

Tags: svn, hook, post-commit

I modified our original repo for the dev checkout portion of our site. I tested the repo and all functions works properly. When I enabled the post-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
/var/www/repos/XXXXX/autoupdate/autoupdate (which is a simple C compiled)
```

I keep getting this Subversion commit failed Merge of file: 200 OK error:

> Commit failed (details follow):
>   MERGE of '/repos/XXXX_new/trunk': 200 OK (http://s15399220.onlinehome-server.com)

If I run the executable by hand it works fine and updates my dev checkout properly. I understand this error is misleading and that the commit works properly and that it is the hook that fails.

Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who still experience this problem and tried everything :

The problem in my case was the type of checkout
svn co http://.... instead of svn co file:///path_to_repo

Comment: You're doing a SVN checkout in your post-commit script?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214883/post-commit-hook-produces-error-on-svn-commit-but-works-when-run-on-manually-on/18229879#18229879).

You might have better luck if you put debug messages into your post-commit hook so that you can see where exactly it is failing. Not sure why you're conducting a merge in the post-commit hook but that is a recipe for problems down the line.

Comment: @user2733937 Can you tell us what was the issue and what you did to solve it? Other people who search Stackoverflow for issues similar to user will benefit from your insight. Plus, you can _accept_ your answer and gain reputation points.